# Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined (How to use a javascript library from the command line, or an html file)

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, terminal

I'm new to javascript and programming in general. I would like to use this:
https://github.com/CesiumGS/gltf-pipeline
It's a tool to convert models into compressed formats.
This is my code:

```
const gltfPipeline = require("gltf-pipeline");
const fsExtra = require("fs-extra");
const processGltf = gltfPipeline.processGltf;
const gltf = fsExtra.readJsonSync("model.gltf");
const options = {
  dracoOptions: {
    compressionLevel: 10,
  },
  separateTextures: true,
};
processGltf(gltf, options).then(function (results) {
  fsExtra.writeJsonSync("modeldraco.gltf", results.gltf);
  console.log('done');
  const separateResources = results.separateResources;

  for (const relativePath in separateResources) {
    if (separateResources.hasOwnProperty(relativePath)) {
      const resource = separateResources[relativePath];
      fsExtra.writeFileSync(relativePath, resource);
    }
  }
});
```

I copied this file, saved it as `compress.js` (because it rhymes) and I then ran it with
`node compress.js` - this is how I'd run a python file.

Error is: `Cannot find module 'gltf-pipeline'` which makes sense. So, I did:

`node -r gltf-pipeline compress.js` but I get the same error.

So, I moved to HTML/JS, where I made an index.html file and linked with a `<script>` tag `compress.js` and the `gltf-pipeline` `index.js` file. These are the errors:

```
index.js:3 Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined
    at index.js:3
(anonymous) @ index.js:3
compress.js:3 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

So how is this done? Either as a webpage or command line would be helpful.
This is my folder structure by the way, maybe that's the issue.

```
basefolder|
          |- gltf-pipeline| library files in here
          |- compress.js
          |- index.html
          |- model.gltf
```

gltf-pipeline works when used as a command line tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## **No.**

You can't do that with Javascript.

JS is served to the client.

Whilst NodeJS runs on a server.

These are the [differences](https://nodejs.dev/learn/differences-between-nodejs-and-the-browser) between node and browser JS.

also for the module error try

```
npm install gltf-pipeline
```

Look at [NPM](https://www.npm.com) to install Node Packages
Also take a look at the [NodeJS Tutorial](https://nodejs.dev/learn/introduction-to-nodejs)